# Not working shortcut CTRL+R on Ubuntu 17.04 with gnome shell (in nautilus and browser)

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

If I will change an option in gnome-tweak-tool (tweak tool > keyboard and mouse > show all input sources > on or off > re logging) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will be working for a while (to the reboot). How to fix it

update/30/07

If look only to browser. Sometimes works shortcut set:
**1.** **F12** and **CTRL**+**SHIFT**+**J** - open console (Browser)
**2.** **CTRL**+**R**, **f5**, **CTRL**+**F5**, **CTRL**+**SHIFT**+**R** - refresh (**CTRL**+**R**, **F5** for the entire system)

Sometimes:
**1.** <s>**F12**</s> and **CTRL**+**SHIFT**+**J** - open console (Browser)
**2.** <s>**CTRL**</s>+<s>**R**</s>, <s>**f5**</s>, **CTRL**+**F5**, **CTRL**+**SHIFT**+**R** - refresh (**CTRL**+**R**, **F5** for the entire system)

How to make it permanent? )

Comment: What should Ctrl+R do?

Comment: In nautilus or browsers ctrl+r to reload(refresh) window or tab

Comment: Does `F5` work?

Comment: f5 doesn't work too

Comment: so your question is how to make it permanent? You should say so in your question.

Comment: But this should work by default. I described the problem and not a feature, or not?

Comment: just noticed, ctrl+r switched to ctrl+shift+r and ctrl+f5, it strangely, for what...